# Would the "Purple Fawn" in this context refer to a shop?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature, animals

> Wodger, of the **"Purple Fawn,"** and Mr. Jaggers, the cobbler, who also sold old second-hand ordinary bicycles, were stretching a string of union-jacks and royal ensigns (which had originally celebrated the first Victorian Jubilee) across the road.

This sentence is from *The Invisible Man* by H.G. Wells. In this scene, the village people are preparing for the Whit Monday festival(?). I can tell that Woder and Mr Jaggers are names of people and Mr. Jaggers is a cobbler, but what is Wodger’s ‘purple fawn’?

Would I be right to understand it as the name of a shop, with Wodger being thus the shopkeeper? As far as I know, a *fawn* is some kind of a deer, right? Is it clear to a native speaker what *The Purple Fawn* refers to?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a literary name rather than English usage per se.

Comment: I disagree. There is clearly a convention in English (particularly British English) whereby an author may make reference to an animal and the reader understands it means a drinking establishment or hostelry. It is one of those quirks of English language and usage that this site is superbly qualified to document.

Comment: Yeah, my first inclination would be to take it as the name of an inn or pub.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Strongly disagree there. The fact that the name appears in a novel is entirely irrelevant here—it might as well have been in a newspaper article. The point of interest, and the crux of the question, is that it's clear to any native speaker what _The Purple Fawn_ is, even though it's never explained. The fact that it's never explained and yet crystal-clear to any native speaker makes it very much a matter of established English language usage, rather than lit-crit.

Comment: @Janus Proper names are almost always off-topic per se. Here, from an etic perspective, 'of the "Purple Fawn" '  might mean that Wodger is a member of the "Purple Faun" club, rock group, secret society, shop (as OP guesses) ... The actual meaning is only decipherable given an understanding of the book in question. Off-topic.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I still disagree with that. I've never read a word of the book, and I still immediate recognised it as a pub name, as did several other people here (though of course I don't know if they've read the book or not)—it's not so much about the name itself, but about the established convention behind the name. And we have plenty of questions about names (like the _Ukraine vs. The Ukraine_ one, etc.), which are considered on topic.

Comment: @Janus A useful test is 'Is this usage treated in a dictionary of English or a grammar?' Apart from when it comes to deciding on apostrophe and plural usage, proper nouns are usually given a wide berth. 'Pub naming conventions' are treated in other publications (if at all – the the crazy examples I've listed below come from a list of unconventional examples).

Comment: I always figured *The Frog and Nightgown* was a "parvenu", not a long-established name for a hostelry (quirky collocations of animals, vegetables, etc. being particularly featured in the naming conventions of nationwide UK pub chains in the 70s). But today I learned something - the original Frog and Nightgown was in [The Village Subway, N Carolina](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Village_Subway). It's not even *British*, fer chrissakes!

Comment: The "Purple Fawn" would seem to be a humorous reference the common English pub name the "White Hart" (Wikipedia claims it is the fifth most common name). "Hart" is the archaic term for a mature stag. The "White Hart" name may be a reference to the mythical English folklore character of Herne the Hunter,  who incidentally gets a mention in Shakespeare's "The Merry Wives of Windsor"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is more likely to be the name of an inn, which are frequently named after animals. Shops were generally not so named.

(In an age when few people were literate, English inns and public houses would often bear a sign with a distinctive image, often of an easily recognisable animal or object.)

A fawn is a young deer.

Note well: There is a clear and definite convention in English (particularly British English) whereby an author may make reference to an animal and the reader understands it means a drinking establishment or hostelry.

Comment: True, but off-topic.

Comment: I voted to close. But now I completely agree with Mike 100%.

Comment: You could add that the naming convention is usually **The [adjective] [animal]**: nearly always singular, definite, and with the animal modified by an (often strange or ill-fitting) adjective. You wouldn't have a pub named “Horses”, for example, or “Ten Dogs”.

Comment: That's not true. There is a pub in my home town called the Three Frogs.

Comment: And while a few old pubs have strange or ill-fitting adjectives, most quirky names of this type are recent inventions by people trying to sound folksy. Where I grew up most pubs had very simple names - The Lamb, The Fox, The Swan, The Plough, The Royal Oak.

Comment: The Bofors Gun And Giblets, The Youth Hostel Card With Handle, The Yolly Yumbo Yets, The Road To Domestos, Foglas & Damp, The Rose And Dalek, The Misplaced Apostrophe's ... very amusing, but off-topic.

Comment: @mikeagg All right, include numerals in the ‘adjective’ group. The ill-fittingness of the adjective is a recent addition, but it's become to widespread (and recent pub names so numerous compared to old ones) that it's still true to say it's _often_ the case. Plus personally I've never seen a pub with a name of this type that was not definite, though I'm sure there are some here and there. All the examples you give are definite, too. So in general, yes, it is true. “The Three Frogs” works fine, but “Three Frogs” or “A Cat” are highly unusual.

Answer (score 3):

Beyond following common naming principles, the other thing that identifies it as the name of an establishment - probably a pub or inn - is that it is capitalized as a proper name.

A purely descriptive sentence referencing a young deer of odd colouration would refer to a 'purple fawn', not the 'Purple Fawn'. The capitalization identifies it as a proper name, and hence identifying someone or some thing, and not a generic use of the word.